# What's the best way to draw chart with discrete values on Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, canvas, charts

I have a Canvas with dynamic width. I need to draw a chart on this Canvas. Due to the amount of the measured values and the business area specificity it's not possible to use third-party controls and components.

The chart shows the level of some measurement that is discrete. The X axis indicates the time of the measurement. In the worst case every pixel of the chart can have different level. So it looks like this:
[image: Chart]

My first approach just to make it working was to draw a line for every pixel. So my code looks like this:

```
        MyCanvas.Children.Clear();
        var random = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < MyCanvas.Width; i++)
        {
            var line = new Line()
            {
                X1 = i,
                X2 = i,
                Y1 = MyCanvas.ActualHeight,
                Y2 = MyCanvas.ActualHeight - random.Next(0, (int)MyCanvas.ActualHeight),
                Stroke = Brushes.Blue
            };

            MyCanvas.Children.Add(line);
        }
```

This code does what I want it to do. It draws a chart like this one:
[image: Chart]

But it seems that it is not an optimal way to do things like this one. My chart should support panning and zooming and it takes around 200-350ms to redraw a chart on every user request. That's too much (1000/350 = 2.85fps).

I don't have much experience in WPF so my question is - what is the most optimal way to draw such chart? Maybe I need to use Paths and Geometry objects but I can't say for sure that it will give much perfomance gain until I implement it. Also I don't know what kind of Geometry I need to use. It seems that LineGeometry matches my expectations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many points do you need? You shouldn't draw every point, but only a fixed number of points. If you have more points than you can draw then you can use math functions for approximating shape of the data.

Comment: @FCin , the number of points is equal to MyCanvas.Width

Comment: Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483292.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

I'll have another shot at answering this, without data binding this time. Given the need for high performance the best approach would probably be to use a custom FrameworkElement. Here's an example that draws 10,000 samples and is able to maintain 60fps on my laptop, with each sample being updated once per frame:

```
public class FastChart : FrameworkElement
{
    private Pen ChartPen;
    private const int MaxSampleVal = 1000;
    private const int NumSamples = 10000;
    private int[] Samples = new int[NumSamples];

    public FastChart()
    {
        this.ChartPen = new Pen(Brushes.Blue, 1);
        if (this.ChartPen.CanFreeze)
            this.ChartPen.Freeze();
        ClipToBounds = true;
        this.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;

        var rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < NumSamples; i++)
            this.Samples[i] = MaxSampleVal / 2;
    }

    private void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // update all samples
        var rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < NumSamples; i++)
            this.Samples[i] = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(MaxSampleVal, this.Samples[i] + rng.Next(11) - 5));

        // force an update
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        // hacky clip to parent scroller
        var minx = 0;
        var maxx = NumSamples;
        var scroller = this.Parent as ScrollViewer;
        if (scroller != null)
        {
            minx = Math.Min((int)scroller.HorizontalOffset, NumSamples - 1);
            maxx = Math.Min(NumSamples, minx + (int)scroller.ViewportWidth);
        }

        for (int x = minx; x < maxx; x++)
            drawingContext.DrawLine(this.ChartPen, new Point(0.5 + x, 1000), new Point(0.5 + x, 1000 - this.Samples[x]));
    }

}
```

A few things to note here:

1. the pen you use to render the lines needs to be frozen, failing to do this will result in a huge performance decrease.
2. if your chart is inside a ScrollViewer (say) you'll want to clip to the visible portion of the screen. In my example above I've just hacked it in by checking if the parent is a ScrollViewer, you may need to do this differently depending on your circumstances.
3. as you can see, I'm subscribing to `CompositionTarget.Rendering` to update the chart values and force a render. this is known to sometimes be called more than once per frame, but there are workarounds for this so I'll leave it to you to find one.

In any case, here's an example of how you would use this control (I've hard-coded the width here, obviously you'd want to binding it to a property in your view model or something):

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="theScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <controls:FastChart Width="10000" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

And here's a still from the (animating) result:

[image]

The only problem with this is that it doesn't use Canvas, but I think in order to get the performance you want you're going to have to ditch that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy to do, but I'd strongly recommend you use data binding.

1. Create an ItemsControl.
2. Give the ItemsControl an ItemsPanel of type Canvas.
3. Bind the Canvas Width and Height to elements in your view model specifying the extents of each axis.
4. Wrap the whole thing in a Viewbox so that it scales automatically, irrespective of width and height.
5. For each element in your ItemsControl list create a view model containing X1/Y1/X2/Y2, then use a DataTemplate to render those items using those values to draw a vertical line.

So basically your main view model should look something like this (which by way of demonstration is generating random data points):

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private IEnumerable<DataPointViewModel> _DataPoints;
    public IEnumerable<DataPointViewModel> DataPoints
    {
        get { return this._DataPoints; }
        set { Set(() => this.DataPoints, ref this._DataPoints, value); }
    }

    public int ChartWidth { get; } = 1000;
    public int ChartHeight { get; } = 1000;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        this.DataPoints = Enumerable.Range(0, this.ChartWidth)
            .Select(x => new DataPointViewModel {X1 = x, Y1 = this.ChartHeight-1, X2 = x, Y2 = this.ChartHeight - 1 - rng.Next(this.ChartHeight) });
    }
}
```

The view model for the items in your collection need to provide the points for the line that is used to render them:

```
public class DataPointViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private double _X1;
    public double X1
    {
        get { return this._X1; }
        set { Set(() => this.X1, ref this._X1, value); }
    }

    private double _Y1;
    public double Y1
    {
        get { return this._Y1; }
        set { Set(() => this.Y1, ref this._Y1, value); }
    }

    private double _X2;
    public double X2
    {
        get { return this._X2; }
        set { Set(() => this.X2, ref this._X2, value); }
    }

    private double _Y2;
    public double Y2
    {
        get { return this._Y2; }
        set { Set(() => this.Y2, ref this._Y2, value); }
    }
}
```

And then your XAML simply uses these to render a line for each data point on a Canvas control:

```
<Viewbox>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataPoints}" Width="{Binding ChartWidth}" Height="{Binding ChartHeight}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Line Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1" X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" X2="{Binding X2}" Y2="{Binding Y2}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Viewbox>
```

This will all in turn generate the following output:

[image]

Comment: I must mention that I have huge collection of 'DataPoints' so in your solution I need to update DataPoints property constantly  Have you compared the performance of constant updating of DataPoints property to the performance of simple Canvas redrawing? I want to keep update rate of the chart around 60fps when user scrolls it. I think that ItemsControl uses the same Add method on Canvas. Am I wrong? I wanted to run your example locally to measure it by myself but I can't find your implementation of ObservableObject anywhere in the internet.

Comment: Ah, that's a pretty important detail. In this case I probably wouldn't use WPF, high performance was never one of its primary design features.

Comment: ObservableObject is part of MVVM Light, you could use ViewModelBase instead or indeed anything else that support INPC. But yeah, if you need real-time high performance then forget data-binding, you're probably going to have to resort to DirectX or something.